# SQL DB2 Select multiple columns values for multiple instances of IDs

Tags: sql, performance, select, db2, multiple-columns

Here is my data:

```
| ID | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 |
|-------------------------------|
| 1  |  NULL  | value1 | value2 |
|-------------------------------|
| 2  |  NULL  | value3 |  NULL  |
|-------------------------------|
| 3  | value4 |  NULL  |  NULL  |
|-------------------------------|
| 4  | value5 | value6 | value7 |
|-------------------------------|
| .. |  ...   |  ....  |  ....  |
```

Here is what I need to select:

```
| ID | ID2 | FIELDX |
|-------------------|
| 1  | 10  | value1 |
| 1  | 10  | value2 |
| 2  | 20  | value3 |
| 3  | 30  | value4 |
| 4  | 40  | value5 |
| 4  | 40  | value6 |
| 4  | 40  | value7 |
| .. | ..  |  ....  |
```

The order of the data doesn't really matter. What matters is that each ID appears once for every associated FIELD1,2,3... value. Please note that there are many fields. I just chose to use these three as an example.

My attempt at the solution was this query:

```
SELECT x.ID, a.ID2, x.FIELDX
FROM (
SELECT t.ID, t.FIELD1
FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1 t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.ID, t.FIELD2
FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1 t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.ID, t.FIELD3
FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1 t
) x
JOIN SCHEMA2.TABLE2 a ON x.ID = a.ID
WHERE x.FIELDX != NULL
WITH UR;
```

While this does do the job, I would rather not have to add a new inner select statement for each additional field. Moreover, I feel as though there is a more efficient way to do it.

Please advise.

Comment: If there is an opportunity to normalize your database table(s), do that. It may help in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB2 doesn't have an explicit `unpivot` and your method is fine.  A more efficient method is probably to do:

```
SELECT id, id2, fieldx
FROM (SELECT x.ID, a.ID2,
             (case when col = 'field1' then field1
                   when col = 'field2' then field2
                   when col = 'field3' then field3
              end) as FIELDX
      FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1 x join
           SCHEMA2.TABLE2 a
           on x.ID = a.ID cross join
           (select 'field1' as col from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
            select 'field2' from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
            select 'field3' from sysibm.sysdummy1
           ) c
     ) x
WHERE x.FIELDX is not NULL;
```

This doesn't necessarily simplify the code.  It does make it easier for DB2 to optimize the joins.  And it only requires reading `table1` once instead of one time for each column.

As a note:  you should use `fieldx is not null` rather than `fieldx != null`.

Comment: Yeah, this makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the tip at the bottom too.

Comment: Hmm...
After converting your code to work with my tables, it seems that there is a problem. It runs but nothing is returned; it's just an empty result set. I've triple checked all fields to make sure everything matches up. At a glance can you spot any issues?

Comment: @LethalLeftEye . . . This would occur if the values in the `c` subquery did not match the values in the `case` statement.  Try dropping the final `where`, to be sure that you get lots of rows.  The other possibility is that the `join` isn't working.

Comment: You were spot on. Thanks for the diagnosis. +239486230

Comment: Sidenote: DB2 has very good support for values so the table c could be expressed as `( values ('field1'),('field2'),('field3') ) c (col)` or even `( values 'field1','field2','field3' ) c (col)`